# Evaluating $\int_0^1 x \, \text{d}(x^2)$ using Sums

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How would one integrate $\int_0^1 x \, \text{d}x^2$ using the definition of the integral (no substitutions or FTC)? Is this considered a Riemann integral, and what's the physical interpretation of $dx^2?$

I'm not sure what the analogue of $dx^2$ is for the Riemann sum. It's not $1/n^2$ because $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^*\cdot 1/n^2=0$, where $x_i^*$ belongs to the ith interval in some partition of $[0,1]$. The answer is $2/3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your notation is a bit ambiguous. I would interpret

$$\int_0^1 x (dx)^2$$

as a Riemann integral, whose value is given by its right hand Riemann sums:

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^N (i/N) (1/N)^2.$$

This limit turns out to be zero, which is true because $\sum_{i=1}^N i = O(N^2)$, so the overall quantity is $O(1/N)$. Similar notation appears in stochastic processes, specifically surrounding Ito's formula, where an integral like this one turns out to *not* be zero.

By contrast, I would interpret

$$\int_0^1 x d(x^2)$$

as

$$\int_0^1 x \frac{d}{dx}(x^2) dx = \int_0^1 2x^2 dx.$$

which is indeed $2/3$. One way to see that this notation makes sense is to realize that this is the same as

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^N (i/N) ((i+1)/N)^2-(i/N)^2)$$

which is a "Riemann-Stieltjes sum", where we multiply by the change in $x^2$ rather than the change in $x$ on each interval.